# How to remove the grey box around navbar dropdown menu hovering

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm customizing the navbar and, while I can change the color of the item when I hover over it, there is a grey box around the item as well. I have tried using in `CSS`:

```
.navbar-nav a:hover{
  color: #f51227;
  border: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

I've downloaded the `bootstrap CSS` files, as some of the answers I found, suggested I edit the `bootstrap.css` file. I have no idea where to look or how I now add this `.css` file to my `.html` as I'm using `jumbotron` as well so I will need that linked and not sure where that is in the `.css` file or which `.css` file it is actually in. I got all sorts of `.css` files from the download.
I'm at a loss at this point and at the point I'm going to leave the grey bar there.
Any Insight is greatly appreciated.

```css
.navbar-nav a:hover{
      color: #f51227;
      border: 0px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Nav bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #FFFEB0;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: #f51227;"> MLB </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Menu </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" style="background-color: #FFFEB0;" style="text-decoration: none;" style="text-shadow: none;">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Burgers </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Snacks & Salads </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Sweets </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Feedback </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to remove grey box around navbar (on hover), you need to change your HTML file. You added there some style and there is a problem. I recommend to you to whole styling add to CSS files (not to HTML).

Delete this in your HTML file:
[image]

After that, there is a following result on hover:
[image]

Comment: Deleting this piece of code did not directly fix it but what you said about keeping all styling in css file and not in both html and css, is what made me lose the unwanted grey bar. I am now moving all the other styling to my css file. Probably a rookie mistake. Thank you for your help! =)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

```
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: No it wasn't. it was for the dropdown menu. Thanks for your input =)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this, because I am not sure what are you talking about hover and other stuff?

> **WARNING**

Please don't edit `bootstrap.css` file directly, You can overwrite CSS property of bootstrap by creating new CSS file but directly changes in the root files is not correct

```css
.navbar-nav a:hover{
      color: #f51227;
      border: 0px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
 }
 
li.nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Nav bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #FFFEB0;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: #f51227;"> MLB </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Menu </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" style="background-color: #FFFEB0;" style="text-decoration: none;" style="text-shadow: none;">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Burgers </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Snacks & Salads </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Sweets </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Feedback </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. When you run that code it is the grey bar on the dropdown menu that I wanted to delete. Turns out I was styling both html and css which now makes sense as to why it clashes, giving me the unwanted highlight/bar.

Comment: can you share a photo of that, in your question so we know which Graybar you talking about

Answer (score 0):

you can just remove this class "navbar-light" in your HTML

Comment: i tried this but all that did was change the color of the navbar items to hyperlink blue

Answer (score 0):

I also felt problem with navbar in the past. I solved the problem by clicking the right mouse on the navbar and then clicking on inspect it brought debugging console where I could experiment the item(here navbar) by changing the value of the desired properties.
Hope this might help.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Great idea. I did this and was able to identify the area i was needing to color. Thanks =)